# How to draw 'biohazard' with swing

Tags: java, swing, shapes

I'm practicing my swing abilities for the upcoming test, and fried gave me idea to draw biohazard sign like this :

[alt text http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/8372/lab6b.gif](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/8372/lab6b.gif)

I could draw the circles with Elipse2D, but then I somehow need to cut those 3 triangles. Any ideas how I can do that ?

Comment: I know I'm being pedantic, but that's the radiation hazard symbol, not biohazard ;) Although the actual biohazard symbol could be another good one to try with Swing if you're practising. It has lots of circles :) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Biohazard.svg).

Comment: @Rich That'd be a damn good coding competition for SO :)

Comment: @Chris: I implemented the real biohazard but I dont think this is the right place to put it..

Comment: Post it up on Pastebin (http://pastebin.com/) and then give us the link :)

Comment: @Chris : Hey please find it at http://pastebin.com/HSNFx7Gq I left the outer triangle coat for the reader. :) 
The screenshot is shown below. The below one does not look as good as the svg counterpart. But thats java2d raw graphics,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Java2D and canvas for this. The things that you may be using are, Circle and Arc. You should have three arcs with 30 degrees.

I tried using simple graphics over the frame.

Here is an attempt

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Biohazard {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Biohazard();
    }

    public Biohazard() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Biohazard");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MyComponent());
        frame.setSize(260, 280);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            int height = 120;
            int width = 120;
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(60, 60, height, width);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawOval(60, 60, height, width);

            int swivels = 6;
            int commonx, commony, commonh, commonw;

            for(int i=0;i<swivels;i++){
                commonx = commony = 120-i*10;
                commonh = commonw = i*20;
                g.drawArc(commonx, commony, commonh, commonw, 60 , 60);
                g.drawArc(commonx, commony, commonh, commonw, 180 , 60);
                g.drawArc(commonx, commony, commonh, commonw, 300 , 60);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The original one : source code can be found at http://pastebin.com/HSNFx7Gq

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Arc2D`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Arc2D.html) class to draw each line by specifying the `start` and `extent` parameters in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is actually quite easy (I'm not sure how the Swing API handles lines). Draw lines coming out from the center to the points on the circumference of a circle, and just skip those portions for line drawing.